# Help converting code using httlib2 to use urllib2

Tags: python, screen-scraping, urllib2, httplib2

What am I trying to do?

Visit a site, retrieve cookie, visit the next page by sending in the cookie info. It all works but httplib2 is giving me one too many problems with socks proxy on one site.

```
http = httplib2.Http()
main_url = 'http://mywebsite.com/get.aspx?id='+ id +'&rows=25'
response, content = http.request(main_url, 'GET', headers=headers)
main_cookie = response['set-cookie']
referer = 'http://google.com'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': main_cookie, 'User-Agent' : USER_AGENT, 'Referer' : referer}
```

How to do the same exact thing using urllib2 (cookie retrieving, passing to the next page on the same site)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [cookielib](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cookielib.shtml), it'll handle all the cookie related work as automatically as a web browser would.

Example:

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))

#Get the first page with the cookie, installing it in the cookie jar automatically
opener.open("http://yoursite.com/set-cookie")

#Get the second page, passing on the cookie in the cookiejar.
opener.open("http://yoursite.com/other")

#Alternatively, you can also install this opener as the default urllib2 opener:
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
#Now all urllib2 requests will use cookies:
urllib2.urlopen("http://yoursite.com/other")
```

Comment: Great, cookielib is the way to go! Do I have to use opener.set_proxy() and opener.add_header() for proxy and header support? My existing code takes a slightly diff. approach. It does something like req = urllib2.Request(url), how to fit this in your code? Thank you!

Comment: Once you create the opener, you could also install the opener as the default one, so that it's used for every urllib2 call (added above):

urllib2.install_opener(opener)